# C++ variable redeclaration within nested loops

Tags: c++, gcc, syntax-error, variable-declaration

Below is a code snipped with 3 nested loops. Variables curs and tempv are getting redeclared at each iteration of the outermost for-loop. This should have given me error but I am able to run it successfully without errors on gcc 4.8.4.

```
for(int i = 0; i<lend; i++)
{
    string curs = vstring[digits[i]-'0'];
    vector<string> tempv;
    for(int j = 0; j<v.size(); j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k<curs.size(); k++)
        {
            tempv.push_back(v[j] + curs[k]);
        }
    }
    v = tempv;
}
```

Is it fine to redeclare variables within for-loop? I have an understanding that in C++ a variable cannot be redeclared in the same scope.

Comment: You get brand-new objects for every iteration.

Comment: If the compiler says it is fine, it _is_ fine.

Comment: You declare them only once in the loop scope. The scope is entered and left each iteration.

Comment: @DyZ: unfortunately, *in general* in C++ it's not a great metric for code correctness or standard adherence. There are several errors for which the standard doesn't require any diagnostics, or he may be relying on compiler-specific extensions.

Comment: you did use `int j=0` and `int k=0`. The way you expect `j` and `k` to work, `tempv` also works like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **”** Variables `curs` and `tempv` are getting redeclared at each iteration of the outermost for-loop

No, they're getting *instantiated* at each iteration. Created, and at the end of the block, destroyed. Modulo optimization done by the compiler.

Scopes are a compile time notion. Something you see by inspection of the code. Instantiations are a run-time effect. The same variable declaration can be executed any number of times, instantiating the variable that number of times. Well, except if it's `static`, in which case it's instantiated once.

> **”**  I have an understanding that in C++ a variable cannot be redeclared in the same scope.

It cannot be redeclared *directly* in the same scope, but it can be redeclared in a **nested scope**. And you have a number of nested scopes. Let's consider them:

```
for(int i = 0; i<lend; i++)                      // ← For loop scope.
{                                                // ← Block scope.
    string curs = vstring[digits[i]-'0'];
    vector<string> tempv;
    for(int j = 0; j<v.size(); j++)              // ← For loop scope.
    {                                            // ← Block scope.
        for(int k = 0; k<curs.size(); k++)       // ← For loop scope.
        {                                        // ← Block scope.
            tempv.push_back(v[j] + curs[k]);
        }
    }
    v = tempv;
}
```

Formally the `for` loop is *defined* by an equivalence to a corresponding `while` loop placed in an outer block that contains the declaration of the loop variable, if any. However,

C++17 §6.3.3/1:

> **”** Names declared in the *init-statement*, the *for-range-declaration*, and in the *condition* of `if`, `while`, `for`, and
>   `switch` statements are local to the `if`, `while`, `for`, or `switch` statement (including the controlled statement),
>   and shall not be redeclared in a subsequent condition of that statement nor in the outermost block (or, for
>   the `if` statement, any of the outermost blocks) of the controlled statement; see 9.4.

For example, in your code the outer `for` loop's `i` cannot be redeclared directly in the block that constitutes that loop's body, even though it's a nested scope, but can be redeclared in the inner nested loop.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it fine to redeclare variables within for-loop? I have an understanding that in C++ a variable cannot be redeclared in the same scope.

It's one single *lexical* scope, where these variables are declared once. The fact that the execution enters it repeatedly is irrelevant - it's not like you get duplicate definition errors for variables that are declared in a function that gets called many times. As always, each time you enter a scope you get a new instantiation of variables defined in it.

In other words: scoping rules are about the static, lexical structure of the program, which is unrelated to how the program flow of execution will actually happen; they act as a blueprint for its runtime behavior, in that they instruct the compiler about how to parse the rest of the block and what code to generate for each time the scope is entered.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly legal, and in fact, it is used all the time. Each iteration can be viewed as a brand new scope in this context.